# How to create folder in directory in iphone and android

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

can you please tell me how to create folder in directory in android (SDCard) and in IOS.?I also need to count number of folder in same directory.
I have directory File://SDCard/test . here one by one create folder .During application launch i need to count number of folder in dame directory .

What is directory of IPhone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Cordova File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) which is based on the W3C File API. It is used to read, write and navigate file system hierarchies.

**List Files and Folders**

In order to list/count the lists and files inside a directory you have to use the [**`DirectoryReader`**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#DirectoryReader) object.

Supported Platforms:

- Android
- BlackBerry WebWorks (OS 5.0 and higher)
- iOS
- Windows Phone 7 and 8
- Windows 8

Example:

```
function success(entries) {
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
        console.log(entries[i].name);
    }
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("Failed to list directory contents: " + error.code);
}

// Get a directory reader
var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();

// Get a list of all the entries in the directory
directoryReader.readEntries(success,fail);
```

**Create Directory**

In order to create a directory you have to use the [**`DirectoryEntry`**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#DirectoryEntry) object. This object contains the *getDirectory* method which creates or looks up a directory.

Supported Platforms:

- Android
- BlackBerry WebWorks (OS 5.0 and higher)
- iOS
- Windows Phone 7 and 8
- Windows 8

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Local File System Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-x.x.x.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

      // Wait for Cordova to load
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

      // Cordova is ready
      function onDeviceReady() {
          window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onFileSystemFail);
      }

      function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
          console.log(fileSystem.name);
          var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;
          directoryEntry.getDirectory("newDir", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail)
      }

      function onDirectorySuccess(parent) {
          console.log(parent);
      }

      function onDirectoryFail(error) {
          alert("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
      }

      function onFileSystemFail(evt) {
          console.log(evt.target.error.code);
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Local File System</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for replay can you please tell me what i take in this "newDir" so that i will check on simulator(iphone).if it success how can i check this on simulator.

Comment: In iOS, this code will create a folder named 'newDir' inside Applications/PHONEGAP_APP/Documents/. In Android, in the case where the device has an SD card, this code creates the  'newDir' directory at the root directory of the SD card storage. Otherwise it will be created in the internal storage.

Comment: Applications/PHONEGAP_APP/Documents/ ..? where is check in simulator?i didnot find any of these folder

Comment: The full path is /var/‌​mobile/Applications/PHONEGAP_APP/Documents/. However, when using an iPhone simulator the path is /Users/loginname/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/YOUR_APP/Documents

Comment: Hello i am able to create folder How to create text file in this folder ?