# creating folder in android using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, directory, hybrid, hybrid-mobile-app

How to create a folder in Sd card of the mobile runnig android ( the application is an hybrid app ., is it possible to do so with the help of javascript ? )

So only we can use HTML or JS and JQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , you can do this. Please go through this post which is already answered.

[How to create folder in directory in iphone and android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119372/how-to-create-folder-in-directory-in-iphone-and-android)